# Display "Warning" screen for the first time of each user session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is a VB.NET web based app. I need to display a warning screen for the first time.  I've already created a modal panel that I can call via code using `modalpopUp.Show()`.

I'm doing this within the `Page_load()` of the Master Page.  I'm thinking all I need to do is check for the existence of some dummy session variable.  If the variable doesn't exists, then I show the screen and set the session variable.

Since it's the master page it will check the page with every page hop through the application, but after the session expires it will show the screen again and set the variable.  I believe my sessions are set to expire in 15 mins.

I was thinking

```
If Session("SomeSession") Is Nothing Then
   modalPopup.show()
   Session("SomeSession") = " "
End If
```

Is there any example code for this?

Comment: Better use a cookie that expires after one day.

Comment: By "first time" do you mean just the first time ever? like accepting the conditions of the site? if so, you need to use the database and save that information in the user table. Then after the user login read the DB to check while reading other info from user DB. If not, you can use like this: If Session("SomeSession")="" then Session("SomeSession")="logged" modelPoput.show() End If